# Posterior distribution as a distribution for a new random variable?

Tags: random-variable, posterior, bayes

So in Bayesian framework one uses observed data $X=\{x_1,...x_n\}$ to update the prior $p(\theta)$. My question is it justified to say that $p(\theta|x_1,...,x_n)$ corresponds to a new random variable itself?

Comment: What is your understanding of what a random variable is?  After all, "$p(\theta|\ldots)$" refers to a *probability,* not a random variable, so your clarification of this point would be helpful.

Comment: @whuber, well my mathematical understanding of a random variable is any measurable function from $\Omega$ to some measurable set, but in this context, what I mean is after all $p(\theta|x_1,...,x_n)$ is probability distribution and one can define $F(\theta= t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t} p(\theta|x_1,...,x_n)$ for it to make a random variable out of it. But I don't know if its mathematically justifiable?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but the posterior from one set of observations can be the prior for a second set (if the situation is otherwise the same), sure.

Comment: @Glen_b, well that I know and it follows from Bayes rule. But this is a different thing that I am asking. I want to know if this new pdf(posterior) would give rise to a *genuine* random variable. So if the data is observed in a sequence, I will get the random variables $\theta_0,\theta_1,...,\theta_n$, with pdfs $p(θ),p(θ|x_1),...,p(θ|x_n)$ respectively.

Comment: The sequence of pdfs must be $p(θ),p(θ|x_1),$ $p(θ|x_1, x_2),$ $ \ldots, p(θ|x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$. Your question doesn't quite make sense to me, but maybe we can unpack it a little. The posterior is a conditional distribution. So just think about conditional distributions for a minute. Is the $X|Y$ in $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ a different random variable from the $X$ in $f_X(x)$? -- that might depend on what you mean/on what you're doing. Is my weight (unconditionally) a different random variable to my weight at noon today?

Comment: @Glen_b, that is very true, but the point is can one, *mathematically* claim(prove) that then these distributions are assignable to new random variables each. Intuitively this make sense as all of these pdfs are different but I am not sure if I am not saying gibberish.

Comment: I am not clear enough about what you're trying to say at all.

Comment: @Glen_b, well I did my best. I know that those are posteriors and you can calculate them using Bayes rule. The question here is can you consider each of that posteriors as a pdf for a seperate random variable?! (of course they are going to be dependant and even probably make a markov chain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta|x_1,...,x_n$ is a random variable. The posterior distribution is its density.

EDIT: Regarding your question in the comments, this is sort of intrinsic to conditional probability. Conditioning a RV reduces the sample space and therefore defines a new random variable. From *A Course In Probability* (Neil A. Weiss, 2006):

> **DEFINTION 5.1 Random Variable**
>
> A **random variable** is a real-valued function whose domain is the sample space of a random experiment. In other words, a random variable is a function $X: \Omega \rightarrow  \Re$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space of the random experiment under consideration. (p.177)

further

> ... conditional probabilities are no different than ordinary (unconditional) probabilities except that the sample space changes from the original one to the event being conditioned on. (p.126)

Since conditioning changes the sample space, we necessarily have defined a new random variable.

Furthermore, the fact that the posterior has a probability density is a consequence of it being a random variable, and clearly it is not the same random variable as the prior or the likelihood, otherwise it would be distributed the same way. Here's a simple example.

let $X \sim Binomial(\theta)$ and $\theta \sim Beta(a,b)$. Then, from conjugacy, we have $\theta | X \sim Beta(a+\sum X_i, b + n - \sum X_i)$. This is clearly a different random variable from $\theta$.

We could just as easily say $\theta | X = W$ and $ W \sim Beta(a+\sum X_i, b + n - \sum X_i)$, if maybe the conditional notation is what's confusing you here.

So to summarize: that the posterior is a new random variable is intrinsic to the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: May I ask you for a reference as well. Preferably a mathematically oriented one.

Comment: Updated my comment, but you can reference any introductory probability text, as your question boils down to a simple question about the meaning of conditional probability.

Comment: The distinction between a random variable and its distribution is important. A random variable, *qua* measurable function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}),$ can remain the same while its distribution function can change when the *probability* on $\mathcal{F}$ changes. Thus, it is possible for *one and the same* random variable to have different distributions.  (This point of view is essential for understanding [Girsanov's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem), for instance.)